# DLL station.config location

Tags: c#, dll, labview

I have a DLL (and associated station.config file for it's settings) that I wrote in c# and a test winform application to verify its functionality. It works perfect.

When I reference the dll and call it using LabVIEW, my LabVIEW application errors out staying it cannot find the station.config file in c:blah\blah\users\the User logged in ID\blah\someguid location (sorry I can't remember the exact location as its in work and i'm at home now).

I put station.config in the folder and it works fine.
I want it to reside in the same folder as the dll and not any folder to do with the user logged in.

It's compiled in debug mode. Whats going on ?

Comment: Sounds like a file reference error. As I understand it the DLL calls the station.config file? Are you using relative paths in your DLL? Labview will set the main path depending from where it is run and what you specify, it looks like this path is used.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code is pointing to the location of the station.config file.

A simple way to fix the issue would be to add an argument to your dll to allow the caller to set the path.  You could then place the config file anywhere, use LabVIEW to determine where the station.config file is located and pass the path to your dll.